# Where do I place monitors for the best [possible] recording of groups of singers?

Tags: recording, microphones

I will need to record a group (approx. 20 children) of students performing a piece.  The piece relies on using a pre-recording backing track the the students will need to hear during the recording.  I have access to a Midas M32 board, two monitors, and two Audix ADX-51 choral mics.

The students will be positioned in a half-circe, only one student deep.  They are little ones and performing only ever in unison.

What is the best way to position the equipment?  Ideally, the students would be able to clearly hear the backing track but the choral mics would pick up the smallest amount of the backing track, allowing me to adjust it in the final mix.  I was thinking of putting the monitor wedges on the floor about 10' from the singers, the choral mics more like 5' away and elevated.  Is there a better arrangement?

Comment: Will also be dependant on how many deep the group is, which again will affect how many wide. Also, how many part singing? Unison, 4 part, or what? And, it will be better to use a couple of tracks dedicated to the backing tracks, rather than use the bleed to the two mics you'll use, which can't really be helped, but that can be partially eliminated by judicious placing of those two mics, obviously.

Comment: @Tim I have updated to include those questions.  The backing track is a simple stereo audio file, so I will have that loaded on its own 2 tracks.  The question is how bothersome the bleed of the backing track on the vocal tracks will be.

Comment: And I guess 20 in-ears is out of the question?... Also, will the monitors be actual monitors, with the live mics in them as well as backing track? If so you, feedback concerns might play a role. I don't have the experience to know, but I *suspect* that actually putting the mics *behind* the monitors might be better for both purposes.

Comment: @AndyBonner no, I don't have 20 in-ear monitors.  (Nor would I want to be tasked with cleaning them after they were use by second graders!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the monitors in the optimum position for the singers to hear them.  They have to be heard.  Pushing them further away won't solve anything.  Position the mics in the optimum position to record the singers.  You're GOING to record bleed from the monitors.  It might as well be clean and close.  This will probably mean positioning both speakers and mics in front of the singers, aimed at them.  The Audix ADX-51 mics are cardioid, so the obvious place for the speakers is dead behind them, in their null.

Flipping the polarity of the monitors MIGHT help minimise bleed.  But be careful.  A bit of straightforward bleed may be preferable to reverberant, out-of-phase artifacts.

You may find you have to put very little of the backing track into the mix.  That's OK.   Try to get a good live sound - track and singers - in the room.  Then just record it.

Comment: Tried this today in a rehearsal/sound check environment.  There was definitely bleed on the vocal track but it was very slight.  Positioning the monitors directly behind the mics - in their null - was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm visualizing your placement correctly, it seems reasonable. It sounds like the distance from voices to mics will at least be significantly less than the distance from monitors to mics. Make sure to use the mics' pickup pattern to reject as much monitor as possible.  Use the bass rolloff switch on the ADX51 to keep out the low frequencies from the backing track. (Second-graders voices aren't going to be producing much below 150 Hz for sure!)

One idea about controlling bleed further: Would it be possible to set the mics and monitors in place in advance and make sure they don't move?  Is the backing track playback coming from the same equipment that's recording?

If yes on both, you could record a take ahead of time capturing the backing track with the mics, *without the singers* and save it in a separate track.  Add this track to your mix *inverted* to [approximately] subtract the bleed.  (I know this is asking for a level of control over the stage that you may not have in a school assembly setting. I've only ever used this trick when recording vocals in a home studio.)

Answer (score 1):

Mics 5' in front of singers. Monitors 10' in front of singers. Mics as high as possible - maybe 7-8' in the air. Monitors so the wedge side isn't facing up, so they project along the floor. With 20 singers, there could be two rows of ten, with the taller ones, or better singers in the back row. Think about rostra blocks for the back row, or even two tiers.

Or try monitors closer to the choir than the mics, for less, almost no bleed. The dimensions and echo effect of the room might need to be considered also.

You really need to listen with cans to what happens, and place mics/monitors in optimum positions. Before the event. Good luck!